# Can't start jar under 64 bit engine (Cant load IA 32-bit.dll) + Cant Include library from Current path with System.load()

Tags: java

First of all I program in Netbeans IDE on Windows 7 x64.
I am using a java native library with dll's.
I was implementing the librarys in Netbeans and everything works fine!
But when I compile the project and try to run it via the command prompt "java -path/file.jar"
I am getting errors like: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. Can't load library
I could fix that by loading the dll in the program either with System.loadLibrary("WiiUsej") where i have to put the dll in the system32 folder 
or by System.load("path/WiiUseJ.dll"). My goal anyway is to load the dll's from the same folder where the .jar file is. Does anybody know how this works?

The next problem is that after including the dll i get an error when i try to run the program on my 64 bit machine. Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a 64 bit platform.
I was checking already for a solution on the internet which was saying i have to install a java 32 bit client.
I did that and ran it via "java -path/file.jar -d32"
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM

Maybe the solution is quiet simple but I was checking for hours on the internet and I am desperate! I dont get why it works when I run it in Netbeans and not in via the console.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you start the 32 bit java.exe, not the (default) 64 bit one.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you are still *using* the 64 bit JVM.  Run this command in the same shell that you are trying (and failing) to launch your application.

```
java -version
```

This will tell you which version of Java you are actually running.

If you are seeing the 64-bit one, you either need to change your shell's %PATH% variable, or use the full pathname for the 32-bit Java executable.

Comment: you were right. I am starting in x64 bit. I was trying the following:
'C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\...\dist\file.jar"'
I got the error that it couldn't find the dependent libraries.
I was running this program on XP 32 bit and it ran.